# Git: How to pull only files casing changes?

Tags: git

When I enter on master branch `git pull` it says that my branch is up to date.
But It is not, because some file names differs from remote repo, e.g. `Mycomoponent` should be `MyComponent`. What should I do to pull those changes?

Comment: Is `Mycomoponent` in the question a typo of `Mycomponent` or the real name of a source file? And what's your operating system? If it's a typo, `Mycomponent` and `MyComponent` are identical on Windows.

Comment: Did you do a `git pull` or a `git pull origin master` and are you sure you were on master when you did that?

Comment: I was on master but I did `git pull` only

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It happen on windows.